# Find second maximum number in a list - HackerRank -- Python

Tags: python, list

I am just trying To solve [Find second maximum number in a list](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-second-maximum-number-in-a-list/problem) problem on HackerRank.

Here is my code :

```
lst = [] 
n = int(input(""))  
arr3=[]
for i in range(0, n): 
    ele = int(input()) 
    lst.append(ele)
    for i in lst:
        if(i not in arr3):
            arr3.append(i) 
arr3.sort()
x=len(arr3)
print(arr3[x-2])
```

when i run the program on VScode IDE it runs fine, but when i test in HackerRank builtin IDE it return message as Runtime error stating
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: are you submitting with `if __name__ == "__main__":` ?

Comment: it means you are hitting some string field/cell with some string that can't be converted to int.

Comment: no i am no submitting with if __name__ == "__main__

Comment: It seems that you pass different input when you run it in VS Code.

Comment: try using split to convert your string to list of strings then you can convert these elements to int

Comment: no it works absolutely fine with same input from hackerank in vscode:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the problem: [Second Max in a List](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-second-maximum-number-in-a-list/problem)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())

my_array = list(arr)

print(
    max([x for x in my_array if x != max(my_array)])
)
```